# Android Eclipse build app with source library files

Tags: android, eclipse, build, jar

I am trying to build an application with the source library files.
I added the source as a project and checked 'is library'
now in my other project all library references are still broken.
First I used the jar for reference but I needed to chance something
in the source that's why i want to build it with the sources of the jar.
Does anybody know how i can build my app with the sources of the jar library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to clean/build the proyect on which you added the library project? That usually solves the issue.

Comment: Yes I did that also, and removed all references to the jar file in the original project also before adding the sources of the jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem of the source libs not found in Eclipse I did the following steps:

Created a new workspace

Renamed the dirs as the project names

Imported both projects

Deleted all refs to the jar in the main project

Add a reference in the main project to the source libs

Answer (score 1):

First as you said you have to mark the source project as library:

[image]

And then on the other project, go to properties/android and on the bottom add the 1st proyect to the library:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that too, when I add it I also have a green checkbox, after i reload the tab the green checkbox changes in a red cross

Comment: Please check that both projects are on the same directory, it seems that the reference is broken. And that the library project folder has the same name as the library proyect on eclipse.

Comment: Both projects are in the same workspace, i removed and imported
them to be sure but it still a red cross, i also typed the path to relative in the project.properties.
I dont have a clue anymore

Comment: Really strange... and removing all references, closing Eclipse, and try again maybe?

Comment: I managed to fix it, I deleted the whole workspace, made a new one, imported both projects,renamed the dirs, added the lib sources to the main project and now it works.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Can you post that as answer and then accept it to close the question?